# Is there a trick to defeat red helmets?

Tags: unepic

I am kind of struggling with defeating red helmets in unepic. Although I managed to get 5 of them down one by one for the quest to get frost magic I am having a hard time solving the quest where I should rescue some frost/water monster which is located in a room with like 10 of these nasty little creatures. So any tricks or a bullet proof strategies out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are three crucial parts of getting them down:

1. Aim

   - The first task is to get the aim on one of the helmets without getting shot.
   - Sometimes one might simply get into aiming distance without activating the helmets.
   - Often on has to run forward, aim and immediately run back.
2. Shoot:

   - Once your little hero aims at the helmets you can shoot them by running into shooting distance, shooting, running back.
   - This is very much about timing but should work pretty well.
3. Weak points

   - All helmets belong to a certain category that defines their resistance as well as their weaknesses.
   - While it makes no sense to attack fire with fire. Ice bolts should bring down fire helmets down pretty fast.
   - Those pets following you might help their as well.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a way to kill them much faster than with arrows.

SPOILERS BELOW, move MOUSE over to show:

spoiler 1/4:

> They are elemental.

spoiler 2/4:

> They are related to the fire element (you noticed that they throw fireballs).

spoiler 3/4:

> Their weakness is in the opposite element.

spoiler 4/4:

> Their weakness is to ice. With wand of ice, I kill them in 2 hits.